# undefined is not an object 'this.props.route.push' (React Native)

Tags: javascript, ios, navigation, react-native

I am working on a react native app using [react-native-custom-navigation](https://github.com/superdami/react-native-custom-navigation)

However, I am getting an error message reading `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.route.push')`. I am not sure how to fix this so that I can successfully navigate to a new view?

LoginWrapper.js

```
 var React = require('react-native');
 var Parse = require('parse/react-native').Parse;
 var ParseReact = require('parse-react/react-native');

 var AppWrapper = require('./AppWrapper');
 var Routes = require('../Routes')

 var {
  TouchableHighlight,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  View,
 } = React;

 var LoginWrapper = React.createClass({
  mixins: [ParseReact.Mixin],

 getInitialState: function() {

  return {
  error: null,
  signup: false

  };
 },

 observe: function() {
  return {
  user: ParseReact.currentUser
  };
 },

 updateUsername: function(text) {
  this.setState({username: text}); 
 },

 gotoProfile: function(){
  this.props.route.push(Routes.Profile());
  },
updatePassword: function(text) {
this.setState({password: text}); 
 },

 render: function() {
  if (this.data.user) {
  return (
    <View style={{marginTop:100}}>
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.logOut}>
        <Text>Logout</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.gotoProfile}>
        <Text>Profile</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
      <AppWrapper />
    </View>
  );
}
return (
  <View>
    <View>
      {
        this.state.error ?
        <View><Text>{this.state.error}</Text></View> :
        null
      }
      <View style={{marginTop:200}}>
        <Text>Username</Text>
        <TextInput style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}} value={this.state.username} onChangeText={this.updateUsername} />
      </View>
      <View>
        <Text>Password</Text>
        <TextInput style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}} value={this.state.password} onChangeText={this.updatePassword} />
      </View>
      <View>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.submit}>
          <Text>{this.state.signup ? 'Sign up' : 'Log in'}</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
      <View>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.toggleSignup}>
          <Text>{this.state.signup ? 'log in' : 'sign up'}</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    </View>
  </View>
);
},

submit: function() {
var self = this;
var username = this.state.username;
var password = this.state.password;
if (username.length && password.length) {
  if (this.state.signup) {
    console.log('signup');
    var u = new Parse.User({
      username: username,
      password: password
    });
    u.signUp().then(function() {


      self.setState({
        error: null
      });
    }, function() {
      self.setState({
        error: 'Invalid account information'
      });
    });
  } else {
    Parse.User.logIn(username, password).then(function() {
      self.setState({
        error: null
      });
    }, function() {
      self.setState({
        error: 'Incorrect username or password'
      });
    });
  }
 } else {
  this.setState({
    error: 'Please enter all fields'
  });
 }
},

logOut: function() {
 Parse.User.logOut();
}, 

  toggleSignup: function() {
    this.setState({
    signup: !this.state.signup
    });
   }

});

module.exports = LoginWrapper;
```

Routes.js

```
class Routes {
static register(name, handler) {
 if (this.handlers == null) this.handlers = {}
  this.handlers[name] = handler
 }
static get(name, params) {
 if (this.handlers[name] == null) throw new Error('unknown route')
 return this.handlers[name](params)
}
static Login() {
 return {
  component: require('./components/LoginScreen'),

  title: 'Login',
  titleStyle: {
  color: '#ddd',
  fontSize: 22
  }
 }
}
static Profile() {
return {
  component: require('./components/ProfileScreen'),
  title: 'Profile',
  titleStyle: {
color: '#ddd',
fontSize: 22
}
}
}

}

module.exports = Routes
```

Comment: You can start by `console.log()`-ing `this`, `this.props` and `this.props.route` to see which one is undefined.

Comment: Ok, I just did that. `this.props.route` is undefined.

Comment: I don't see where `this.props` (and `this.props.route` is defined/initialized); Do you have something like ` props: { route: [] },` above `gotoProfile: ...`?

Comment: Can you show us the parent component, or where / how this component is receiving this.props.route ? Thanks.

Comment: @Kenney no I don't have that defined. I'm not sure what I would put in the definition.

Comment: @Nader I edited my question, adding more code. Hopefully you can get a better understanding now.

Comment: How is LoginWrapper.js receiving the route prop? Is it explicitly being passed from a parent component?

Comment: @Nader I don't think so. How would I explicitly pass the route prop to LoginWrapper.

Comment: Ok, maybe try this: instead of onPress={this.gotoProfile}, use onPress={ () => this.gotoProfile() }